# Compare dates with deferent formats framework 4.5 c# web forms

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

A part of my project is to write a function that will generate an increasing number for every day for every record I have to store in a database table.  My problem is that when I try to compare the DateTime.Now with the column I have in my database, I try to compare Datetime with Date so I never have equality on the days. My code explains better than me my issue:

```
var r = (from i in context.vehicles
         where  i.InsertionDate == DateTime.Now
         select i); // In this query i cant compare the two dates. The one is datetime and the other is date format
int result3 = 0;
if (r.Any())
{
    var result = r.OrderByDescending(ii => ii.IncreasingNumberOfTheDay).FirstOrDefault();
    int myint = Convert.ToInt32(result.IncreasingNumberOfTheDay);
    result3 = myint + 1;
}
else
    result3 = 1;
```

Comment: What is your field type in the database? You shouldn't be using strings anywhere, basically...

Comment: In my database the field is datetime. I am using mssql server 2008

Comment: So why are you converting `DateTime.Now` to a string at all? It's very confusing...

Comment: My mistake let me edit my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you just want:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // Just fetch the date part.
var query = context.vehicles.Where(v => v.InsertionDate == today);
```

Avoid string conversions if you possibly can.

If your `InsertionDate` includes times, then *either* you need to try to get the SQL query to truncate that to a date, or you could use:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
var query = context.vehicles.Where(v => v.InsertionDate >= today &&
                                        v.InsertionDate < tomorrow);
```